# How to overlay texts on an Image using jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I am trying to make something that uses the same concept as the image below;

[image]

An image like background with text overlaying it.

I tried to make a card and give it a backgroundColor of the image, but I got an error;

[image]

**What I want to do is overlay some texts on an image**, like the image above.

So please how do I arrange this code. I need everything to be in a single composable because I need to populate it.

Thanks for your understanding and assistance, In advance.

Please, I'd happily provide any more info needed.

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper Thanks for feedback, honestly.. Kinda true though.. But I did take most of the codelabs and skiped some.

Comment: What feedback, they took it down. Honestly the policies...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `Box` to overlay composables.

Something like:

```
@Composable
fun ImageAndText(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    painter: Painter,
    contentDescription: String,
    text: String 
) {
    val shape =  RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
    val height = 100.dp
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .height(height)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(White, shape = shape),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = contentDescription,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clip(shape)
        )

        Text(
            text = text, 
            color = White
        )

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Box` as a direct `Child` of your `Card` and put the `Image` and `Text` in it and set its `contentAlignment` to `Alignment.Center`.

Use the `Image` composable to host your desired image instead of card's backgroundColor since it only accepts `Color`.

```
@Composable
fun ImageWithTextInMiddle() {
    Card {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(100.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Image(
                // painterResource(successInfo.successInfoImageId)
                painterResource(R.drawable.img),
                contentDescription = "",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            )

            // will display in the middle of the image
            Text("Some Text In the middle")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]